# Kullback Leibler Divergence of 2 Histograms in MatLab

Tags: matlab, distance

I would like a function to calculate the KL distance between two histograms in MatLab. I tried this code:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13089-kldiv

However, it says that I should have two distributions P and Q of sizes n x nbins. However, I am having trouble understanding how the author of the package wants me to arrange the histograms. I thought that providing the discretized values of the random variable together with the number of bins would suffice (I would assume the algorithm would use an arbitrary support to evaluate the expectations).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask the author about it?

Comment: I don't think I would obtain an answer: questions are unanswered since last year. I was hoping someone here provided some insight or shortcut for coding the function.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this particular implementation, since it doesn't handle zero probabilities properly. I would use [this implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20688-kullback-leibler-divergence) instead. All you need to do is specify two probability vectors of equal length; for example `P=[0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]` and `Q=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you link to requires that the two histograms passed be aligned and thus have the same length NBIN x N (not N X NBIN), that is, if N>1 then the number of *rows* in the inputs should be equal to the number of bins in the histograms. If you are just going to compare two histograms (that is if N=1) it doesn't really matter, you can pass either row or column vector versions of these as long as you are consistent and the order of bins matches.

A generic call to the function looks like this:

```
 dists = kldiv(bins,P,Q)
```

The implementation allows comparison of *multiple* histograms to each other (that is, N>1), in which case pairs of columns (with matching column index) in each array are compared and the result is a row vector with distances for each matching pair.

Array `bins` should be the same size as `P` and `Q` and is used to perform a very minimal check that the inputs are of the same size, but is not used in the computation. The routine expects `bins` to contain the numeric labels of your bins so that it can check for repeated bin labels and warn you if repeats occur, but otherwise doesn't use the information.

You could do away with `bins` and compute the distance with

```
 KL = sum(P .* (log2(P)-log2(Q)));
```

without using the Matlab Central versions. However the version you link to performs the abovementioned minimal checks and in addition allows computation of two alternative distances (consult the documentation).

The version linked to by eigenchris checks that no histogram bins are empty (which would make the computation blow up numerically) and if there are, removes their contribution to the sum (not sure this is entirely appropriate - consult an expert on the subject). It should probably also be aware of the exact form of the formula, specifically note the use of `log2` above versus natural logarithm in the version linked to by eigenchris.